# ORACLE 9.0.1 driver for jdk 1.7 download to be used for jboss 7

Tags: jdbc, oracle9i

I want to download driver "JDBC 9.0.1 drivers " for jdk 1.7 download.
I want to use it for  oracle 8.0.5 .

Thanks
Hiren

Comment: hello  gfelisberto - Thankyou for reply.I tried to search But no where i am getting it.i am trying since 2 days .I get to oracle site but it says classes12.zip which is jdk.1.2 and jdk 1.3 but my jdk version is jdk 7.Hence i have posted the question.

Comment: A JDK is backwards compatible. Meaning that you can run code built with a JDK 1.2 version on 1.7. You will just not be able to take advantage of new features in the Java Programming language. Did you try using the Oracle9i 9.0.1.4 Thin driver? If I'm not mistaken a few years ago I used that driver with a JDK 1.5 and Oracle 10g server.

Comment: hello Gfelisberto,Could you please send the driver path.I am not abloe to find any from internet.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the 9.0.1.4 Driver for JDK 1.2 and 1.3: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc901-088158.html

This should work on JDK 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

To use lower version of java driver use ironcamar.xml and package the jar file into the ear file .Dont use global module for this application.Instead use the driver jar of lower version in the ear file.This will make applicatin connect to the DB using the jar in the ear file and allow it to work as it did in earlier version of jboss